# Clarification on pointer to a function conversion

Tags: c++, function-pointers

A function type (lvalue) can be converted to a pointer to function (rvalue).

```
int func();
int (*func_ptr)() = func;
```

But from (4.1/1)

> An lvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted
>   to an rvalue.

Does it mean that a lvalue to rvalue conversion is not done on functions? Also, when an array decays to pointer doesn't it return a rvalue which is a pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are lvalues.  A pointer to a function (a data type) can be
either; if you give it a name, it's an lvalue; otherwise, it's not
(roughly speaking).  Pointers to functions obey all of the usual lvalue
to rvalue conversion rules.  For simple types like the basic types or
pointers, the lvalue to rvalue conversion basically means reading the
variable.

```
void func();            //  Declares func
(*(&func))();           //  The expression &func is an rvalue
void (*pf)() = &func;   //  pf is an lvalue
(*pf)();                //  In the expression *pf, pf undergoes an
                        //  lvalue to rvalue conversion
```

Note that there is an implicit conversion of function to pointer to 
function, and that the `()` operator works on both functions and
pointers to functions, so the last two lines could be written:

```
void (*pf)() = func;
pf();
```

As always, the result of the conversion is an rvalue (unless the
conversion is to a reference type).  This is also the case when an array
is implicitly converted to a pointer; both arrays and functions can only
exist as lvalues, **but** they both implicitly convert to a pointer,
which is an rvalue.  But that pointer can be used to initialize a
variable of the appropriate pointer type; such variables are lvalues.

Comment: I see, so the result is nothing but an address which doesn't mean that your reading some value. right?

Comment: The result of what?  The result of a conversion of function to pointer is a value, the address of the function.  It doesn't have an address in memory (which is a characteristic of lvalues).

Comment: The result of function `func` is an rvalue which is an address but not in the sense of rvalue returned from non-function or non-array types, which is the reason why the statement in (4.1/1), right?

Comment: @user1086635 I don't see any difference.  The expression `func` is an lvalue.  The result of the implicit conversion to pointer to function (if it occurs) is an rvalue.  The same as for any other type: given `int i;`, the expression `i` is an lvalue, but if you convert it into some other non-reference type, e.g. `static_cast<double>( i )`, the result of the conversion is an rvalue.

Comment: @user1086635 With regards to §4.1, all it says is that there is no
lvalue-to-rvalue conversion for functions or arrays.  It says nothing
about other conversions, such as array-to-pointer or
function-to-pointer (the results of which are rvalues, since the target
type of the conversion is not a reference).

Comment: I see, so it seems theres a reason why using & operator `&func` doesn't suppress any lvalue-to-rvalue conversion because its actually called a function-to-pointer conversion and same goes in the case of arrays, if i'm correct.

Comment: @user1086635 I wouldn't quite describe it like that, but it's close.  Using the `&` operator explicitly is taking the address of the function: the operand of the `&` operator must be an lvalue, and the results are an rvalue.  The implicit conversion is a conversion, not the `&` operator.  But the result of the conversion is an rvalue, and the semantics of the conversion are the same as using the `&` operator.  So in practice, there's really no difference in what goes on under the hood.