# C++ function-to-pointer implicit conversion: which compiler is right? Clang and GCC disagree

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

```cpp
template <typename Type, Type Func>
struct A
{
};

void func();

A<void(), func> a; // same result with A<void(), &func> a;
```

This code compiles with Clang (including latest 8.0.0), but not with GCC (including latest 9.1).

GCC says: `error: 'void()' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter`

Which compiler is right and why?

## Update

I am guessing GCC is wrong, because the following compiles on both Clang and GCC:

```cpp
template <void()>
struct A
{
};

void func();

A<func> a; // same result with A<&func> a;
```

So contrary to what GCC reports in the first example, `void()` seems to be "a valid type for a template non-type parameter"

Comment: Maybe relevant: `A<void(*)(), func> a;` works

Comment: I suppose that there are no pointers involved (but raw function types) and GCC is right. There is somehow related explanation about function type vs pointer to function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573763/clarification-on-pointer-to-a-function-conversion Anyway, we need language lawyer for concrete answer. Edit: `A<void(&)(), func> a;` is accepted by both compilers and `A<void(&&)(), func> a;` again by clang only

Comment: In the update the type of the non type template parameter is `void(*)()` because it is adjusted. `template<void()> struct A` is equivalent to `template<void(*)()> struct A;` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a2AMt6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similarly to what happens to [function parameter type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#5), if the type of a non-type template parameter is a function type, it is adjusted to pointer to function type [[temp.param]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#8):

> A non-type template-parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be of type “pointer to T”.

So clang is right. GCC bug report already exists [bug #82773](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82773)

---

Only the current working draft of the c++ standard recognizes the process of [substitution](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#names-7.4) of template argument into following template parameters. So it could be argued that the standard is not clear because it does not specify that the type adjustment is performed after each of those substitutions.

Comment: The difference between Clang and GCC is in how they handled the first template parameter, not the second. Clang converted first template parameter from `void()` to `void(*)()`, GCC did not.

Comment: @BorisRasin The first parameter is `void()` in both case. Clang does the adjustment for the non-type template parameter but not GCC. I'am still digging inside the standard to see if the type adjustment should also happen in this case or not, but I suspect it is not clear.

Comment: They both adjust second parameter exactly the same. This has the exact same outcome: `A<void(), &func>`. The difference is in how they handle the first parameter.

Comment: @BorrisRasin As I said, Clang does not adjust the first parameter. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3iPzCx)

Comment: You are right, Clang does not adjust the first parameter. Your answer is still wrong, adjustment of second parameter has nothing to do with it, as problem remains exactly the same with `A<void(), &func>`.

Comment: @BorisRasin You are mixing up the term "argument" and the term "parameter". The  first template parameter is `Type` and its associated argument is `void()`. The second parameter is `Func` its associated argument is `&func`. After substitution of the first parameter by its associated argument into the second parameter, the type of the second parameter is `void()`. The type of the second argument (`&func`) is `void(*)()` . Clang adjust the second parameter type from `void()` to `void(*)()`. So the type of the argument `&func` match the type of the parameter...

Comment: @BorisRasin ... For GCC the second parameter type is not adjusted to `void(*)()` and a non-type template parameter cannot have function type, so GCC complains.

Comment: I am not mixing anything. The template has two parameters. I refer to one of them as `first` and to the other as `second`. So, once again, when `second` parameter is specified as `&func` it has explicit type of void(*)(), so compiler adjustment is not necessary. Yet the problem persists. Therefore: compiler adjustment of the second template parameter has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @BorisRasin The type of the second parameter, `Func`, is not deduced from the type of the second argument `&func`. For type deduction use `auto`. https://godbolt.org/z/-STKFd

Comment: Of course it isn't. No one suggested it is. How is it even relevant?

Comment: @BorisRasion You wrote "once again, when second parameter is specified as &func  it has explicit type of void(*)()". Which lead to 2 options either you are mixing up argument and parameter or you thought parameter type is deduced from argument type. Now I think you should read all of this tomorrow.

Comment: You are right, I was mixing up terms argument and parameter. Sorry about that.